# Open a Summary tag via a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome

I would like to open a `<summary>` tag and see it's content when a hyperlink is clicked.

How would I go about doing that?

At the moment, I can only view the summary tag when a hyperlink is clicked.

When I say summary tag I mean

```
<summary>
```

Here is a snippet, thanks to Praveen Kumar

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="det.attribute("open","false"); return false;">'.$nextLine.'</a>';
```

Which I would like to reference the peak1 image

```
echo '
                    <section>
                        <details>
                            <summary> Peak Image </summary>';
                                # create a bookmark with the id attribute. Used to link from Peak Table rows
                                # create collapsable windows for each peak image 
                                echo '
                                    <details id="det"> 
                                        <summary> Peak 1 </summary>';                                   
                                        echo '<h2 id="peak1">Peak 1</h2>
                                        <img src="open/images/peak1.png" alt="Peak1" height="2500" width="1000">
                                    </details>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar I edited the question.

Comment: Well, what have you got so far?

Comment: Okay, so looking that up, there actually is a `<summary>` tag in HTML5. The thing is though, there's hardly any browser support for it. But that does not explain what you're trying to achieve. So, please elaborate.

Comment: @Roope Chrome supports it.

Comment: Which is why I said _hardly_.

Comment: @Crt Check my answer. Try clicking and doing it. Is that what you are trying to get?

Comment: @Crt See the second snippet. I guess that's what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I edited the question but, your answer helped a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
a + .meta {display: none;}
a:focus + .meta {display: block;}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hello</a>
<div class="meta">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum voluptatem sit sed, aspernatur in doloribus magnam ad deleniti. Aperiam at illo nihil repellat placeat aspernatur, unde soluta aliquam nesciunt beatae.</p>
  <p>Eaque soluta, aliquam aut recusandae voluptates debitis dolore inventore itaque eligendi optio numquam architecto labore neque distinctio quia ducimus qui fuga. Dolores distinctio, tempore iusto odio ipsa, quidem est rem.</p>
</div>
<br />
<a href="#">Hello</a>
<div class="meta">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum voluptatem sit sed, aspernatur in doloribus magnam ad deleniti. Aperiam at illo nihil repellat placeat aspernatur, unde soluta aliquam nesciunt beatae.</p>
  <p>Eaque soluta, aliquam aut recusandae voluptates debitis dolore inventore itaque eligendi optio numquam architecto labore neque distinctio quia ducimus qui fuga. Dolores distinctio, tempore iusto odio ipsa, quidem est rem.</p>
</div>
<br />
<a href="#">Hello</a>
<div class="meta">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum voluptatem sit sed, aspernatur in doloribus magnam ad deleniti. Aperiam at illo nihil repellat placeat aspernatur, unde soluta aliquam nesciunt beatae.</p>
  <p>Eaque soluta, aliquam aut recusandae voluptates debitis dolore inventore itaque eligendi optio numquam architecto labore neque distinctio quia ducimus qui fuga. Dolores distinctio, tempore iusto odio ipsa, quidem est rem.</p>
</div>
```

Or, opening the summary tag, by a hyperlink:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="det.setAttribute('open', 'true'); return false;">Open the Summary Tag</a> &bull;
<a href="#" onclick="det.removeAttribute('open'); return false;">Close the Summary Tag</a>
<br />
<br />
<details id="det">
  <summary>Click on the Link</summary>
  <p>Hey, I am open!</p>
</details>
```

Comment: The second one is what I am looking for but, the first one seems to be supported on more browsers. For the second script, I used the key points in my code as such as it didn't work out.

Comment: I edited the question, but your answer helped a bunch.

Comment: @Crt Lemme try to do it for your question, wait.

Comment: @Crt Change the first snippet to `echo '<a href="#" onclick="det.removeAttribute('open'); return false;">'.$nextLine.'</a>';`

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is a modal window.

Here is a tutorial on how to do that:

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/